# Flutter : Align widget at the bottom of Gridview item

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to place a text widget at the bottom of gridview(G.V) item.

i have an image in G.V item and i want to place a text on center bottom of the image. but i'm not able to do it.

```
child : Stack(
          children: [
            // Image
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: Image.network(
                  "${DummyDataProvider().provideAdoptionList()[index].imageUrl}",
                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
            Text("This is bottom center text") <= how to align this text at bottom center of grid item
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: hi Nagul :  as suggested i did this : Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter) - Stack(fit: StackFit.expand,) [ ClipRRect, Align-Text ]
but it still doesnt work :  i get this error : BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try. You just wrap your text with `Align`

Edited:

```
      Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                child: Image.network(
                    "${DummyDataProvider().provideAdoptionList()[index].imageUrl}",
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
              ),
              Positioned.fill(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Text(
                    'Text Message',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 22.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Hi Brother , thanks for the reply. but the text is still at the top .
i have added the output image url

Comment: @NeerajKumar I edited my answer please check out